# Error: NullPointerException while retrieving the details in sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, nullpointerexception

My database table has data and can be viewed in sqlite database browser.In the following class am getting error...if there is exception it must be caught in catch loop, but still getting an exception dont know how it occurs, please help me to solve....and comment if any info required thank you in advance

DataBaseView.java

```
package com.vibrator;

import android.app.Activity;

import java.util.ArrayList;


//import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class DataBaseView extends Activity{
    DataBaseAdapter DataBaseAdapter;
    ArrayList<String> al;
    Cursor cursor;
    public  SQLiteDatabase db;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.database_view);
        System.out.println("entered in database");

        ListView list =(ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
         DataBaseAdapter=new DataBaseAdapter(this);

         DataBaseAdapter=DataBaseAdapter.open();
             try {


             cursor=db.rawQuery("select * from DETAILS", null);
             if(cursor!=null){
                 if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                     do {
                         String id =cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ID"));
                         String name =cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("NAME"));
                         //String pattern =cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("PATTERN"));
                         //store the values in arraylist
                         al.add(id+". "+name);

                    } while (cursor.moveToNext());

                }
             }
             DataBaseAdapter.close();
         }
             catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "exception occurred", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

             ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, al);

            list.setAdapter(adapter);


    }


    }
```

logcat:

```
08-05 20:25:10.988: E/AndroidRuntime(9500): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-05 20:25:10.988: E/AndroidRuntime(9500): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-05 20:25:10.988: E/AndroidRuntime(9500):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getCount(ArrayAdapter.java:291)
08-05 20:25:10.988: E/AndroidRuntime(9500):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1081)
08-05 20:25:10.988: E/AndroidRuntime(9500):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
08-05 20:25:10.988: E/AndroidRuntime(9500):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
08-05 20:25:10.988: E/AndroidRuntime(9500):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1012)
08-05 20:25:10.988: E/AndroidRuntime(9500):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:381)
08-05 20:25:10.988: E/AndroidRuntime(9500):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:304)
08-05 20:25:10.988: E/AndroidRuntime(9500):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
08-05 20:25:10.988: E/AndroidRuntime(9500):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
08-05 20:25:10.988: E/AndroidRuntime(9500):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
08-05 20:25:10.988: E/AndroidRuntime(9500):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
08-05 20:25:10.988: E/AndroidRuntime(9500):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
08-05 20:25:10.988: E/AndroidRuntime(9500):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
08-05 20:25:10.988: E/AndroidRuntime(9500):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
08-05 20:25:10.988: E/AndroidRuntime(9500):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:801)
08-05 20:25:10.988: E/AndroidRuntime(9500):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
08-05 20:25:10.988: E/AndroidRuntime(9500):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-05 20:25:10.988: E/AndroidRuntime(9500):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-05 20:25:10.988: E/AndroidRuntime(9500):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-05 20:25:10.988: E/AndroidRuntime(9500):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-05 20:25:10.988: E/AndroidRuntime(9500):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-05 20:25:10.988: E/AndroidRuntime(9500):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-05 20:25:10.988: E/AndroidRuntime(9500):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-05 20:25:10.988: E/AndroidRuntime(9500):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: ... `al` is null  ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You usually get **NullPointerException** when you declare but forget to initialize an object/variable.

```
al = new ArrayList<String>();
```

You forgot to initialize the **al** object

Comment: NullPointerException was solved thankyou...but there is something wrong in the code, the exception is getting caught in the catch loop, am not getting how it is occurring please help me to solve..

Comment: this question is done, make another question for further problem and ask again

Answer (score 0):

You never initialize `al`. You define it above, but never create an actual object. Include this in your `onCreate()` method, before you add anything to `al` in your db query:

```
al = new ArrayList<String>();
```